# Android Espresso waitFor.. and Thread.sleep() solution

Tags: android, multithreading, android-espresso

I've just started using Espresso, before that I have tried Robotium. I need to test LoginActivity. The logic is:

1. User enters correct credentials;
2. User sees "Logging in.." string;
3. User waits for string to disappear;
4. User is in MainActivity and sees "You're logged in"

testLogin source:

```
    public void testLogin() throws Exception{
    onView(withId(R.id.login_email)).perform(typeText(LOGIN_EMAIL));
    onView(withId(R.id.login_password)).perform(typeText(LOGIN_PASSWORD));
    onView(withId(R.id.login_loginBtn)).perform(click());
    onView(withText(R.string.loading_logging_in)).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    onView(withText("You're logged in")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
}
```

The problem was that espresso didn't wait for "You"re logged in" string to appear, it was trying to find it while logging still was in process.

logcat:

> com.google.android.apps.common.testing.ui.espresso.NoMatchingViewException:
>   No views in hierarchy found matching: with text: is "You're logged in"

I've tried using Thread.sleep(10000), but it terminates the run on Thread.sleep(10000) and gives me error:

> Test failed to run to completion. Reason: 'Instrumentation run failed
>   due to 'Process crashed.''. Check device logcat for details Test
>   running failed: Instrumentation run failed due to 'Process crashed.'

logcat:

> @@@ @@@ @@@was killed cancelService in HttpReRegistrationService

Before that, I used the waitForActivity(MainActivity.class) method.
Is there any workaround to make this work?

Comment: `thread.sleep()` is almost never an appropriate solution to a given problem.

Comment: yeah, I understand it. Just wanted to try different approaches. Now I'm thinking about switching back to Robotium

Comment: How the login call is implemented? I guess is some sort of async call not on the UI Thread and I guess you're not using AsyncTask for it.

Answer (score 2):

If your login process is busy while trying to log in the user and you're not using AsyncTask (in an appropriate way) your only option is to have your busy resource to implement the interface `IdlingResource` as described [here](http://dev.jimdo.com/2014/05/09/wait-for-it-a-deep-dive-into-espresso-s-idling-resources/).

That way Espresso knows when and how long to wait.

Comment: AI, I have almost the same problem here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25470210/using-espresso-idling-resource-with-multiple-activities. Can you explain/give  me any instructions on how to implement it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Another way of approaching this would be with UiAutomator. I often use it in situations like this. Solutions would be something like this:

```
UiDevice mDevice = UiDevice.getInstance(InstrumentationRegistry.getInstrumentation());

onView(withId(R.id.login_loginBtn)).perform(click());

UiObject loginLoading = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId(your_package_name+":id/loading_logging_in"));
loginLoading.waitUntilGone(15 * 1000); //Give them 15s to login

onView(withText("You're logged in")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
```

Or you could even do it like this:

```
UiObject loginButton = mDevice.findObject(new UiSelector().resourceId(your_package_name+":id/login_loginBtn"));

loginButton.clickAndWaitForNewWindow(15 * 1000); //Again at least 15s to login
```