# Using Espresso idling resource with multiple activities

Tags: android, android-espresso

I have a firstActivity that launches the secondActivity, where in the secondActivity I have a loading Dialog (not AsyncTask), and I need to make Espresso wait until the dialog disappears before it continues with the test.
Where do I have to implement the IdlingResource? How can I make it wait for the dismissDialog() function?

Here is what I've tried to do:

```
  class DocumentLoadingIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {
    private ResourceCallback callback;

    @Override
    public String getName() {
      return "Documnet loading idling resource";
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
      Activity activity;
      try {
        activity = getCurrentActivity();
      } catch (Throwable e) {
        return false;
      }

      if(activity.getClass().getName().equals(EditorActivity.class.getName())
            && activity.loadingDialogShowing() == false) {
        return false;
      }

      return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback callback) {
      this.callback = callback;
    }
  }

  Activity getCurrentActivity() throws Throwable {
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    final Activity[] activity = new Activity[1];
    runTestOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
        java.util.Collection<Activity> activites = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(Stage.RESUMED);
        activity[0] = com.google.common.collect.Iterables.getOnlyElement(activites);
    }});
    return activity[0];
  }
```

This class is implemented in the test class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

1. Your isIdleNow() calls getCurrentActivity() which calls waitForIdleSync() and runTestOnUiThread(). isIdleNow Javadoc says: "Espresso will **always** call this method from the main thread, therefore it should be non-blocking and return immediately." So this won't work as is, but you could call getActivitiesInStage directly from isIdleNow.
2. Your other issue is that you store the reference to ResourceCallback but never invoke onTransitionToIdle, also you should allow for the possibility of more than one ResourceCallback being registered and call onTransitionToIdle on all of the callbacks.

You can do the following:

1. Copy/Paste [IdlingResource](https://android-test-kit.googlecode.com/git/espresso/lib/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/espresso/IdlingResource.java) into **your app** as com.mycompany.IdlingResource.
2. Then have your Activity implement that interface and make sure to call onTransitionToIdle when the dialog goes away and make sure isIdleNow returns false iff the dialog is showing.
3. In your test code, write a "IdlingResourceAdapter" that wraps com.mycompany.IdlingResource and turns it into an Espresso IdlingResource and register that with Espresso.

This will be simpler once this issue is implemented: https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/issues/detail?id=71

Comment: please if you have any project in android studio with working Idle resource, share with as (me) on github. I am trying to implement espresso with idling resource for week:((
I have posted my question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28016562/android-espresso-wrong-set-up-or-work-not-stable
But if anyone has any android studio working project with Idle espresso test, please, share!

Comment: @yogurtearl the links are outdated now. could you update them?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question in my search for a similar answer. Using concepts from Stefano Dacchille's article on [IdlingResources](http://dev.jimdo.com/2014/05/09/wait-for-it-a-deep-dive-into-espresso-s-idling-resources/), I built the following idling resource that waits for a specific Activity to be active before firing. In my case, I know the dialog is showing when a fragment with a specific tag exists. This isn't the same as the OP's test, but the concepts should translate well.

```
public class BusyWhenFragmentExistsInActivityIdlingResource implements IdlingResource {
    private FragmentActivity activity = null;
    private final String fragmentTag;
    private ResourceCallback resourceCallback;
    private boolean wasIdleLastTime = true; // Start off as idle
    private final String name;
    // Need this strong reference because ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry won't hold one
    private final ActivityLifecycleCallback activityLifecycleCallback;

    public BusyWhenFragmentExistsInActivityIdlingResource(
            final Class<? extends FragmentActivity> clazz,
            final String fragmentTag
    ){
        name = BusyWhenFragmentExistsInActivityIdlingResource.class.getSimpleName()+" "+clazz.getSimpleName();
        this.fragmentTag = fragmentTag;
        activityLifecycleCallback = new ActivityLifecycleCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onActivityLifecycleChanged(Activity activity, Stage stage) {
                if (!FragmentActivity.class.isAssignableFrom(activity.getClass())) {
                    return;
                }
                FragmentActivity fragmentActivity = (FragmentActivity) activity;
                if (!clazz.isAssignableFrom(fragmentActivity.getClass())) {
                    return;
                }
                switch (stage){
                    case RESUMED:
                        BusyWhenFragmentExistsInActivityIdlingResource.this.activity = fragmentActivity;
                        break;
                    case STOPPED:
                        BusyWhenFragmentExistsInActivityIdlingResource.this.activity = null;
                        break;
                }
            }
        };

        ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance()
                .addLifecycleCallback(activityLifecycleCallback);

    }
    @Override
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isIdleNow() {
        if (activity==null) {
            return wasIdleLastTime = true;
        }
        boolean isIdleThisTime = activity
                .getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag)==null;

        if (!wasIdleLastTime && isIdleThisTime && resourceCallback!=null){
            resourceCallback.onTransitionToIdle();
        }
        return wasIdleLastTime = isIdleThisTime;
    }

    @Override
    public void registerIdleTransitionCallback(ResourceCallback resourceCallback) {
        this.resourceCallback = resourceCallback;
    }
}
```

To use it, add something similar to this to your test:

```
@Before
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    registerIdlingResources(new BusyWhenFragmentExistsInActivityIdlingResource(
            SomeOtherActivity.class,
            BaseActivity.LOADING_DIALOG
    ));
}
```